# Facebook PHP-SDK not compatible with php 5.2.5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Curl CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220416/php-curl-curlopt-ipresolve)

I have php version 5.2.5 on my server and the facebook login on the API uses "CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE" which i read is only available for PHP 5.3 +.

Is there any alternative or workaround that issue or is the only option to upgrade my PHP?

I keep getting the following notice :

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE - assumed 'CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE' in ** on line 952
```

Comment: I guess you should just upgrade your PHP.. It also increases your security you know.

Comment: I do not have control over the server's php version. I can ask for it to be updated although it will take a while and i need the app done within the next couple weeks. Which is why i wanted to know if there was a way to fix the issue :/

Comment: I've indeed seen this question, but there was no real solution to it (other then upgrading PHP), wanted to know if there was any workaround others found.

Comment: I tried it on my server and it gave me that CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE is 113. Try setting it to the number 113 and try again. Maybe hacking will help :)