# CURL URL Invalid

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I have a problem in my application, is showing the following message

Warning: curl_setopt () [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option in / home/storage/4/f6/25/mwiter/public_html/site/funada/momento_familia/base_facebook.php on line 970

Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 2A03: 2880:10: CF01: face: b00c: 0:4: Network is unreachable thrown in / home/storage/4/f6/25/mwiter/public_html/site / Funada / momento_familia / base_facebook.php on line 977

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It'd be better if you give us some code. (Line 970 for example)

Comment: What url are you trying to access?

Comment: 970:   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

Comment: I'm using this function provided by base_facebook.php protected function makeRequest($url, $params, $ch=null)

Comment: when using the $ facebook-> api ('/ me'); of this error ... sometimes it's right and sometimes it does not, I'm appID and by setting the secret to instantiate the object

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` is not a proper curl option in older versions of curl. The proper values are listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Please see [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11221630/122353) to a similar question.