# Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Network unreachable

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
<?php
session_start();

//included file and use

$app_id = 'xxx';
$app_secret = 'xxx';
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("`http://example/facebook4.0`/", $app_id, $app_secret);
try 
{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}
catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) { } 
catch(Exception $ex) { }

$loggedIn = false;

if (isset($session))
{
    if ($session) 
        {
            $loggedIn = true;
            try {                     //logged here and get data
                $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
                $session, 'GET', '/me'
                ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

               print_r($user_profile); //print data

            } 
            catch(FacebookRequestException $e)  {
                echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
                echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
            }   
        }
}

if(!$loggedIn)  //if user is not online // get link and add scope
{
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('public_profile','email'));
    echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login With Facebook</a>";
}
else
{
    print_r($user_profile); //logout link is generated here 
    echo '<br><br><a href="index.php">Logout</a>'; //print to sceen
}

?>
```

I have set Domain name to localhost and Site URL to `http://localhost/`. 
I have also tried `http://localhost:80` , `http://mydomainname:80` (changing hosts)

this is error I get in response:

```
Facebook\FacebookSDKException Object
(
    [message:protected] => Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Network unreachable
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 7
    [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php
    [line:protected] => 142
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php
                    [line] => 248
                    [function] => send
                    [class] => Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/oauth/access_token?client_id='my key'&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A80%2Fmyapp%2F&client_secret='mykey_secert'&code=AQCYmzsFNUIQG7gUAZ3y-YJHLeIGcF-xyqHotx31MCJGlm16fV9VbVSzlGlx5280-u0Ho3jFjg_REevN5J0LEIPHerY1QaaBYjpkkoIMf6PCwHGj2OIrQDvfyGcUJRK4cJP0YQ8H8HdYw86xEhlcdJHvnObkCU6tSBcVbDWM8uoXJlRqNl6o-IdxoSfbk6IjuCreyagMXvam4vgV0HKxn0nkWaV26k1P6kQP_L1LtXXx2UyUQ1i0jJGL9JiGr1gsUbf5drY_URIrEWzawumpnSWkuxln8hiOtAr_xwM_4cBZwxf3_pWq8YnUotpmzzM5sPhW_ERMYWAdovjZPHu7Xdgs&access_token=329734847193179%7Cd9e5cdb2d0c3cbe1e127827762e94284&appsecret_proof='key_proof'
                            [1] => GET
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                )    
                        )    
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php
                    [line] => 146
                    [function] => execute
                    [class] => Facebook\FacebookRequest
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )    
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\index.php
                    [line] => 52
                    [function] => getSessionFromRedirect
                    [class] => Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )    
                )    
        )    
    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Comment: 1. Can you ping this address ? 2. How do you expect the facebook servers to be able to reach your localhost ? It is possible that facebook will not redirect to an address it cannot reach.

Comment: But the same code where Working and the above codes where running on my localhost till 31th july. suddenly they stop from 1 august

Can u still help me out  ?

Comment: Facebook doesn't ever access your server, so accessing localhost isn't an issue. Make sure your server is setup to allow outgoing connections. Also, see if this works: `$data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/4'); print_r( $data );`

Comment: yes it work and i get an array

{"id":"4","first_name":"Mark","gender":"male","last_name":"Zuckerberg","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/zuck","locale":"en_US","name":"Mark Zuckerberg","username":"zuck"}

Comment: Can you post the result of: `$ch = curl_init("https://google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print($data);`

Comment: it prints bool(false)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question and the OP might have already found the solution. I also bumped into the same issue while working with the [Laravel Socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) plugin.

For posterity, I would like to post the solution here. The issue is explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11220416/1321873): the domain graph.facebook.com resolves to an IPV6 address which some networks may not be configured to route. You can request cURL to resolve IP addresses to their IPV4 values. Set the option `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` to `CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4`.

In the case of the socialite plugin, we had to modify the `FacebookProvider.php` to include the additional option.

**Edit**

To be more specific, Socialite uses GuzzleHttp, and we need to pass this as a parameter to the GuzzleHttp Client method:

```
'curl' => [ CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4]
```

Comment: In which file do we need to include this code? Thanks

Comment: Thanks ! saved my day