# Facebook login Failed connect to graph.facebook.com:443; Operation now in progress

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement facebook login, im having the following code.

```
$helper = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(URL('facebook/login'), $apiVersion = NULL);
try
{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch (Facebook\FacebookRequestException $ex)
{
    // When Facebook returns an error
    return Redirect::to('login')->with('error-message', 'Facebook could not validate your account.');
} catch (\Exception $ex)
{
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // FAIL HAPPENS HERE 
    return $ex->getMessage();
}
```

But i get

```
Facebook login Failed connect to graph.facebook.com:443; Operation now in progress
```

As suggested by [Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Network unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131564/failed-to-connect-to-graph-facebook-com-port-443-network-unreachable) I tryed

```
  $data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/4'); print_r( $data );
```

This results in a page that looks to fail in loading,
As also suggested i tryed

```
$ch = curl_init("https://google.com"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); $data = curl_exec($ch); print($data);
```

this resulted in google being loaded in my page.

unfortunately there is not given a solution, so hopefully someone else can help me out .

// Im on a shared hosting, i cant change php.ini files

Comment: file_get_contents is blocked on a lot of shared hosting servers. most probably it must be a problem with your hosting provider. did your tried contacting the support ? . why not try something like digital ocea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_get_contents was blocked as Sojan V Jose commented, you must enable it to get it working ! As far as I know there is no way arround it.