# Php Curl returns data on local machine but bool false on server

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-access-token

I am trying to get facebook access token

But the url when executed from browser and local machine php script returns true data values. However, when i run the same script from server, it fails and shows bool(false)

the url

```
   $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
    . "client_id=".$config['appId']."&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($config['callback_url'])
    . "&client_secret=".$config['secret']."&code=" . $_GET['code'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $response = curl_exec ($ch);

    var_dump($response);
```

Other urls work on the  server.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Can you get other webpages using cURL? It might be possible that facebook is blocked on your webhost, or cURL all together.

Comment: Yes, I can get other webpages

Comment: but ... can you get other 'https' urls ?

Comment: Yes... I can get other https urls. I tried this very page and it worked !

Comment: when debugging curl, use CURLOPT_VERBOSE... what does CURLOPT_VERBOSE say? `curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>true,CURLOPT_STDERR=>STDOUT));`

Comment: btw, obvious errors, you're not url-encoding appId/secret/code

Comment: My server (free hosting on Hostinger)I believe does not allow connecting to facebook sdk. I am moving to a paid server.

Answer (score 4):

You should check at the [curl error](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-error.php) instead of only looking at the curl_exec result:

> PHP 4 >= 4.0.3, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>   curl_error — Return a string containing the last error for the current session

Try this:

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}


curl_close($ch);
```

**UPDATE**

Try setting this:

```
'curl' => [ CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE => CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4]
```

For more details check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36216204/1016425)

Comment: I am getting Curl error: Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Connection refused. What should be the reason ?

Comment: @user3526204 facebook might either be blocking your server or your server does not allow https connections. This is usually the case with free webhosts to prevent spam.

Comment: @thepieterdc yes that seems to be the problem. I have updated it as an  answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to check [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

> **curl_error** — Return a string containing the last error for the current session

That may help finding what was wrong .

Comment: seconds late than @lloiaconi answer ; )

Comment: No worries, I have upvoted it. I am getting Curl error: Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Connection refused. What would be the reason ?

Comment: try to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);`

Comment: Then maybe your host doesn't allow connection to Facebook SDK ? or can't route domains that resolves to ipv6 ?

Comment: yes that seems to be the problem. I have updated it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have been given to understand from an upvoted answer on one of the other questions that my server Hostinger (free) does not allow connecting to Facebook SDK !!!

I am moving to a paid server !